# Where to create the Articles in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, bucket

I'm trying to understand the best approach to create article items in my sitecore 7.2 project.

Basically I'm considering 2 options:
1 - Create an article as a page;
2 - Create an article as a Site Data Item.

1 - Create article pages under a given page (i.e. My Articles). This way each article would have a specific URL out of the box, easier to understand in Content Authors' point of view;

2 - Have a specific folder (i.e. Article Folder) under Site Data. This way we don't need to have a page for each article - I was thinking to have a single Article page that would render the article fields. However this would require more work in terms of URLs, navigation, etc.

Is there any other ideas? Am I missing something? I was also having a look at Buckets...

Thank you

Comment: Some differing opinions in these answers. Here's a good article which talks about this topic http://cardinalcore.co.uk/2014/07/29/page-vs-non-page-content/ I don't happen to agree with it, but the author makes some good points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with Marek and recommend you opt for option 2.

Storing your articles in folder under a Data node allows those items to be datasourced. This is the principle Sitecore was built on. You can then surface those articles in a number of interesting ways via Widgets such as Promo Panels, prompting the user to click through to read about the article without duplicating its data and requiring Content Editors to manage data multiple times.

It even supports multiple sites, so the Articles can be used in other sites you may add to your Sitecore instance in the future.

As you state it will require extra work in terms of Urls and Navigation but it can be achieved via Sitecore's Wild Card Item and you an even use a great open sourced Module from Sitecore's Marketplace to complete 90% of the work for you. See links below for more information.

You can still implement Marek's point of applying Presentation Details once on the Standard Values of the Wild Cart Item you create. If you are using Sitecore 7 and above you can store all your articles in a Bucket so if you have lots of articles they are stored and searchable in a meaningful way.

- http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2011/09/wildcards-and-data-driven-urls.aspx
- https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Wildcard_module.aspx

Comment: Good point on multi site, if you needed to share articles they would need to sit outside of the content tree. A data source doesn't need to be outside of the content tree however so both solutions can meet that requirement.

Comment: Very true about the datasource doesn't need to be outside of the content tree, it's down to personal approach. For me, I prefer to honour the separation of concerns, the data being independent of every way its being presented.

Comment: Thanks jRobbings, I think I'll go with your suggestion despite being a single site solution. Good to keep following sitecore's principles and mvc's SoC.

Answer (score 1):

In a standard one instance setup the easiest implementation is to create articles as pages.

In Sitecore you want to limit the items in a folder to 100 or less which is best practice to keep the content editors experience optimal.

This then leads you needing a folder structure and a couple options:

1. Manually maintain a folder structure for your articles. For example articles/year/month/day. This gives your editors the most control over the folder structure and allow them to navigate the articles in a more traditional way via a visible folder structure.
2. Use a bucket which automatically generates the folder structure and hides this complexity from the content editor. This takes the manual folder creation and maintenance away from the content editor and are automatically generated based on the configuration you set out for your bucket. The folders wont be visible to the content editor so they will be forced to search in the bucket for any articles rather then navigate the folders.
3. Use the shared source News mover module (https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/News_mover.aspx). This takes a different approach to the above. It works via a traditional folder structure however it generates folders and moves the item on save based on the date field in the article. So the news mover handles the generation of folders however you will still need to check your not exceeding 100 items per folder again for performance when opening folders with large amounts of items.

With all solutions you must still consider the URLs for your articles as they will include the folder structure by default. This is not always acceptable. I prefer to remove the folder structure from the URL. For this you need to create a custom linkProvider and a custom HttpRequestProcessor. Firstly the linkprovider allows you to ensure the new URL is always created and displayed in your site as you want. Next the HttpRequestProcessor ensures that when navigating to the shortened URL Sitecore recognises it as a valid URL and presents the correct page.

By excluding the folder structure from the URL it also adds the additional benefit that the URL is not dependent on the structure. This means editors can change that folder structure and not need to create redirect items to ensure SEO rankings or users bookmarks are not lost.

Comment: Thanks Jason - you've pointed some important aspects. I think I'll go with your suggestion regarding the URL definition and have a better look at News Mover module. In this instance though, I'll create articles in a separate Site Data folder and consider Article as a Data Item and not a Page. Thanks once again and keep the good work!

Answer (score 1):

The cleaner data model is to use the wildcard approach for the URLs and centralize the storage of articles data in a bucket of datasources. This will give you optimum performance and reuse of the data.

However, this isn't how an author thinks about their website. When they use the system, they tend to navigate to the area where they would view articles and try to create a new one there. Authors tend to think in 'pages', so try to hide whatever data model you are using from them and give them the ability to edit the page with Experience Editor.

Some developers try to optimize too far and forget that the authoring experience is likely the most important piece of the delivered solution. The author doesn't care how efficiently you stored the data, only that they can edit it easily and publish efficiently. Whatever model supports that for your author base is how you should implement it.

My recommendation is a page-based approach where the author creates the URL structure with folders and items, something they understand. Then, if you really need to, you can have the primary article data be a datasource-driven component on the page. The user gets to use all the tools they are familiar with (Experience Editor,preview navigation) but you can still store the raw data in a centralized folder. You could then theoretically swap out the article data using DMS rules, or hide information based on authentication or membership status.

Comment: Good point regarding the "author thinking". You are right! Sometimes we tend to forget this. However, in this case, I think I'll try to keep the Articles in Site Data and have authors to add new ones through the Page Editor and not the Content Editor mode. The "page-approach" was my option before reading the replies but jRobbins made some good points. Thank you Jay S.

Answer (score 0):

Go with approach 1: article is a page.

Define all your presentation details on `Article Page` template `__Standard Values`. All new articles will get them. And you can change some of the presentation details for your chosen articles if you want.

If you know that you'll have lot of articles, think about `year/month/day` folder structure, e.g. `articles/2015/06/12`.

---

Approach 2 doesn't give you anything - you still need to have an item for every article. And as you wrote, it would require additional coding which is not required.

Comment: Hi Marek, I got your point but I think the option 2 will be more beneficial in this situation. I'll have latest articles and probably kind of promos based on those articles. Given this, I reckon that I should keep articles separated and then just use them as datasources. Good suggestion though. Thanks Marek.

Comment: @Snapper sure. That's your decision. You can use pages as datasources for other components. And as I always tend to keep content separated from presentation, I still think articles are pages and it would be easier from both you and editors to have them in pages tree. If you don't plan to use them in multiple sites, you'll not get much from having them in the tree outside of pages node. Anyway, your decision. Maybe post some comments when your site is live, whether this decision was good or not?

Comment: Cool @Marek, will do. We had a sitecore review few weeks ago and one of the guys was saying that we need to make sure that personalization is being considered. If I'm not mistaken, this is easier to achieve if we take the approach with datasources. Well... Anyway I'll try to share my solution once I finish it.

Comment: @Snapper yes, you need datasources for personalization. But those item can still be a part of your pages tree. It's about your code and how it uses data from the datasources.